# Why I've RecursionError: maximum recursion depth in quicksort_bad and not in quicksort

Tags: python-3.x

I woul like to know :
With the same list len = 100_000 I've an error only if I call quicksort_bad and not quicksort ?

```
def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    pivot = arr[len(arr) // 2]
    left = [x for x in arr if x < pivot]
    middle = [x for x in arr if x == pivot]
    right = [x for x in arr if x > pivot]
    return quicksort(left) + middle + quicksort(right)


def quicksort_bad(arr, inizio=0, fine=-1):  # Porzione di arr
    if fine == -1:
        fine += len(arr)
    if inizio < fine : # arr con + elementi
        pivot = arr[fine] # prendo l'ultimo come riferimento
        iprog = inizio
        j = inizio
        while j <fine : # considero tutti gli elementi che lo precedono
            if arr[j] <= pivot : # confronto se sono minori dell' ultimo
                arr[iprog], arr[j]= arr[j], arr[iprog] # scambio con prog
                iprog += 1 # incremento indice progressivo dei minori
            j +=1

        arr[iprog], arr[fine]= arr[fine], arr[iprog] # il primo dei maggiori lo scambio con il pivot
        quicksort_bad(arr, inizio, iprog-1)  # parte dei minori o uguali
        quicksort_bad(arr, iprog + 1, fine)  # parte dei maggiori
```

Comment: They should be roughly equivalent, except the first one will be bad if the array is sorted, the second will be bad for a specific other values that are less obviously patterned. (And the first one uses more memory, but that's not really relevant for this case). (Unless I'm missing some bug in #2; #1 is way more readable)

Comment: if you run quicksort(quicksort(arr)) works